# Dynamic UITableView with different number of images

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

I want to develop a feed view with dynamic UITableViewCell having different number of images (upto 4). Refer the attached screenshot.

Any library or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a `UITableViewCell` per feed item, and a child `UICollectionView` to display the images.

Comment: To achieve this, Create 4 view with number of images and based on your images data show hide view.

Comment: inside main stackview  Use two stackview side by side  (each has two imageview). if left has one image then just hide bottom imageview. and if only one image then hide entire right stackview

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Does it work like this, bcz never tried. Is stack automatically covers the hidden part of image by other unhidden image??

Comment: You just need to set isHidden to true when you have two or three images and for one image you can setHidden to true for right side stackview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UITableView`, and each cell may contain either a `UICollectionCell` with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, or I would probably prefer a couple of nested `UIStackViews`:

```
horizontal stack view -> two vertical stack views -> each two imageViews
```

For `UIImageView`s not containing an image you would set `isHidden` to `true`, and thanks to `UIStackView`'s default behaviour they would get hidden as if those imageView's weren't there. Thus you would get desired layout without a lot of effort.

Comment: Sounds perfect. Thanks for the info, I was thinking of similar approach just needed to know if I am going in the right direction

Comment: When only one image is available the first vertical stackview isn't taking full width of horizontal stackview  https://prnt.sc/i71fbo

Comment: @Rajesh I guess you'll have to set `isHidden = true` even on the second vertical stack view, not just on imageViews that are inside of it

Comment: @MilanNosáľ It works

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Only questioner can accept the answer.

Comment: @Rajesh I thought it was you :D

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, I was following the same approach. So, how should i give the layout constraints between 2 imageviews in vertical stack? I should give the height constraint or equal height constraint for those imageviews right? If so, when there is only 1 image, will that image cover the full height of vertical stackview?

Comment: @MBN well, the answer depends on what you want to achieve.. if you want to have them the same height, you can just set distribution on the stackView to be .fillEqually...

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, Yeah i used equal heights constraint and when hiding the second imageview, first imageview is taking the full height. It worked as i expected.Thank you.

Comment: @MBN You're welcome... upvote would be nice ;)